# this.state.due.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this simple `.map()` function that throws the error `this.state.due.map is not a function`. Which is is the best `.map()` for this object?

```
[{…}]

0: {
      amountDue: 354
      avgPrice: 20
    }

<div>
  {this.state.due.map(due => {
    return <p>{due.amountDue}</p>
  })};
</div>
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: Can you share what the `state` looks like initially?

Comment: Please include all relevant code, as text (not an image), in the question.

Comment: Check now, @HereticMonkey

Comment: @adiga this is data that comes from db, so initially the state is empty, so I get the data and save it into the state. The data structure is in the question :)

Comment: Can you please add how you are declaring the state initially to the question? Is it `state = {}` or `state = {due:[]}` or something else?

Comment: Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.due))` just before you output it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to convert that object to an array before you can work with it. [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) should do that for you (If you don't care about the key (`0`):

```
<div>
  {Object.values(this.state.due).map(due => {
    return <p>{due.amountDue}</p>
  })};
</div>
```

If the object key is some sort of unique key however, I recommend using `Object.entries()` and using the key as part of that list:

```
<div>
  {Object.entries(this.state.due).map(([id, due]) => (
    <p key={id}>{due.amountDue}</p>
  ))};
</div>
```

See [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for more information on why key is important.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native map to the Object object, but Note to this example:

```
var myObject = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 };

Object.keys(myObject).map(function(key, index) {
  myObject[key] *= 2;
});

console.log(myObject);
// => { 'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 6 }
```

But you could easily iterate over an object using for ... in:

```
var myObject = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 };

for (var key in myObject) {
  if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    myObject[key] *= 2;
  }
}

console.log(myObject);
// { 'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 6 }
```